Glassmorphism effect with JavaFX
I'm trying to make the UI of my Java Desktop Application with javaFX (on Windows). I want my UI has a Glassmorphism effect, like a Frosty Translucent Crystal for the background. Something like the image (I'd got this from this thread (JavaFX effect on background))
(https://i.sstatic.net/xCVIbGiI.png)
But there the answers use imports and code that java does'nt let me use. I'm working with JDK 22 in VSCode, Maven Project with JavaFX-archetype-fxml.
Also, I'd tried with css in SceneBuilder, but I can't apply the effect to the Stage.
Here's my fxml screen:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>

<VBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="20.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.example.PrimaryController">
   <children>
      <Label text="Primary View" />
      <Button fx:id="primaryButton" text="Switch to Secondary View" onAction="#switchToSecondary"/>
   </children>
   <padding>
      <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0" />
   </padding>
</VBox>

and here's my start app:
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * JavaFX App
 */
@SuppressWarnings("exports")
public class App extends Application {

    private static Scene scene;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        scene = new Scene(loadFXML("primary"), 640, 480);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    static void setRoot(String fxml) throws IOException {
        scene.setRoot(loadFXML(fxml));
    }

    private static Parent loadFXML(String fxml) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(App.class.getResource(fxml + ".fxml"));
        return fxmlLoader.load();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}

There's a way to give my UI that effect?
A code exapmle where I can see how could I apply the Glassmorphism effect to my UI, with the lines, dependencies or modules that I could need

"But there the answers use imports and code that java does'nt let me use" -- Which imports? Which code? What are the errors?

Blur effects

Your issue seems to have nothing to do with the blur effect you are trying to create, and is about not being able to import some packages and classes. Clarify the problem to address that issue. The "suppress warnings" on the application class declaration is also a sign something is wrong in your setup.
